# Nextjs mix SSR and client data in components

Tags: reactjs, random, next.js

I faced the situation when the same component shows mixed data when randomisation involved, html get jumbled data partially from SSR and partially from client rendering.

Here is the code :

```
const Component = (props) => {
    const rand = Math.random();
    console.log('==========================', rand);

    return <a href={rand}>{rand}</a>
}
```

The result is following.

SSR :

```
========================== 0.30408232064749563
```

Client rendering :

```
========================== 0.6842738761932372
```

Result HTML :

```
<a href="0.30408232064749563">0.6842738761932372</a>
```

So the `a` tag get old SSR value in `href` while text value get updated.

Comment: As you've noticed, React assumes that the rendered component from the server and client match. I would suggest doing the rand in a `useEffect` hook, which only runs in the client.

Comment: I could use any kind of isServer check and do it  client side only but it does not solve my problem. The user case required some stuff to be randomised in both cases.

Comment: You can try `useRef` to store `Math.random`. It should be same in the server side and client side both.

Comment: you can try to use a `key` with the same value

Comment: nothing helps really and it seems like issue exists only in production mode

Comment: open an issue on github?

Comment: yeh, that is what I did

Comment: share link to an issue?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13498

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the data identical in SSR and CSR, you should create `Math.random()` in `getInitialProps` and pass it by `props`.

```
const Component = props => {
  console.log(props.rand)
}

Component.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const rand = Math.random();
  console.log(rand);

  return {
    rand
  }
}
```